# TinyMCE: getting started with TinyMCE

Tags: javascript, jquery, tinymce, tinymce-4

Sorry if I am asking a silly question. I just now starting with TinyMCE. I googled it and found examples where they all say to include in tinymce.js. I did that but I am getting a wired screen (as shown below. can anyone please help me, what I am missing

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="jquery-2.2.4.js"></script> 
    <script src="tinymce.js"></script> 
    <script src="theme.js"></script> 
    <!-- Just be careful that you give correct path to your tinymce.min.js file, above is the default example -->
    <script>
        tinymce.init({selector:'textarea'});
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <textarea>Your content here</textarea>
</body>

</html>
```

[image]

Comment: Are you sure, all the CSS is correct?

Comment: @Dan: Could you please tell which CSS I have to pull in. There are so many CSS files, but none of these does not have a name like tinymce.css or similar like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This structure is working for me with TiniMCE 4.5.1:

Head:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="lib/tinymce/skins/lightgray/skin.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="lib/tinymce/skins/lightgray/content.min.css" />
<script type="application/javascript" src="lib/jquery/jquery-min.js"></script>
<script type="application/javascript" src="lib/tinymce/tinymce.min.js"></script>
```

Directories:

```
\lib
    \jquery
           jquery-min.js
    \tinymce
            tinymce.min.js
            \plugins
                    \advlist
                    \anchor
                    \...a lot of plugins
            \skins
                  \lightgray
                            content.min.css
                            skin.min.css
                            \fonts
                                  tinymce.ttf + woff
                                  tinymce-small.ttf + woff
            \themes
                   \modern
                          theme.min.js
```

Hope this help!

Comment: I also found the same in some other website. But it was not straight forward to find these... Thanks for looking into this.